# Schema for storing "binary" values, such as Male/Female, in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, schema

### Intro

I am trying to decide how best to set up my database schema for a (Rails) model. I have a model related to money which indicates whether the value is an income (positive cash value) or an expense (negative cash value).

I would like separate column(s) to indicate whether it is an income or an expense, rather than relying on whether the value stored is positive or negative.

---

### Question:

How would you store these values, and why?

- Have a single column, say `Income`,
  and store `1` if it's an income, `0`
  if it's an expense, `null` if not
  known.
- Have two columns, `Income` and
  `Expense`, setting their values to `1` or `0` as
  appropriate.
- Something else?

I figure the question is similar to storing a person's gender in a database (ignoring aliens/transgender/etc) hence my title.

---

### My thoughts so far

- Lookup might be easier with a single column, but there is a risk of mistaking `0` (`false`, expense) for `null` (unknown).
- Having seperate columns might be more difficult to maintain (what happens if we end up with a `1` in both columns?

Maybe it's not that big a deal which way I go, but it would be great to have any concerns/thoughts raised before I get too far down the line and have to change my code-base because I missed something that should have been obvious!

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: You haven't even developed the tables yet, and you are already expecting them to be filled with bad data (0s for null, and 1 for both Income and Expense columns)? How do you hope to have a working system in such an environment?

Comment: What on earth would you do with an "unknown" transaction type?

Comment: @Jeffrey - Well I would certainly hope that neither of those cases actually happened, I was just trying to think about possible advantages/disadvantages of either schema.

Comment: @kurosch - I am not intending on actually keeping unknown transactions. Rather I was thinking about what the value would be if the transaction hadn't been assigned as an income/expense yet, rather than just defaulting to one or the other.

Comment: @latentflip - Most relational database system have excellent facilities for maintaining data integrety. Instead of hoping the bad data doesn't occur, just verify that the data is always good. Use stored procedures as gatekeepers (and deny update permissions on the tables themselves), use check constraints, foreign keys, etc. Always be as explicit as possible about what data values mean. Make columns non-nullable unless there is an excellent justification otherwise. And then make them non-nullable anyway. :)

Comment: @Jeffrey: That's a good reminder for me to be much more explicit and save myself hassle. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would you store these values, and why?

I would store them as *a single column*. Despite your desire to separate the data into multiple columns, anyone who understands accounting or bookkeeping will know that the dollar value of a transaction is one thing, not two separate things based on whether it's income or expense (or asset, liablity, equity and so forth).

As someone who's actually written fully balanced double-entry accounting applications and less formal budgeting applications, I suggest you rethink your decision. It will make future work on this endeavour a lot easier.

I'm sorry, that's probably not what you want to hear and may well result in ngative rep for me but I can't, in all honesty, let this go without telling you what a mistake it will be.

Your "thoughts so far" are an indication of the problems already appearing.

1/ "Having seperate columns might be more difficult to maintain (what happens if we end up with a 1 in both columns?" - well, this shouldn't happen. Data is supposed to be internally consistent to the data model. You would be best advised preventing it with an insert/update trigger or, say, a single column that didn't allow it to happen :-)

2/ "Lookup might be easier with a single column, but there is a risk of mistaking 0 (false, expense) for null  (unknown)." - no mistake possible if the sign is stored with the magnitude of the value. And the whole idea of not knowing whether an item is expense or income is abhorrent to accountants. That knowledge exists when the transaction is created, it's not something that is nebulous until some point after a transaction happens.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you are suggesting not having any extra income/expense columns, and instead just using whether the cash value is positive or negative to decide?


Don't apologise, advice backed by experience is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting that. Having a signed value for income/expense items (and asset/liablity/equity in double entry systems, despite the non-intuitive signs that laymen have trouble wrapping their heads around) will make your life a lot easier. I wasn't sure whether you had a valid reason for wanting them separate that I wasn't seeing (although I've never found one myself) hence the apologies in advance.

Comment: What you are saying makes a lot of sense now. I am typically dealing with projected future transactions, rather than actual real transactions, but regardless I think following your advice will make life a lot easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use a character. For example, I have a column `gender` in my database that stores `m` or `f`.

And I usually choose to have just one column.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically implement a flag as an nchar(1) and use some meaningful abbreviations. I think that's the easiest thing to work with. You could use 'I' for income and 'E' for expense, for example.

That said, I don't think that's a good way to do this system.

I would probably put incomes and expenses in separate tables, since they appear to be different sorts of things. The only advantages I can think of for putting them in the same table are lost once the meanings are differentiated by flags rather than postitive and negative values.